# Grub overwritten

Tags: grub2, fedora

I've accidentially overwritten my bootloader.  I was prepping some live USB sticks and think I accidentially wrote to my local disk instead of my USB stick.  Now my machine will only boot in to Fedora and only in a live boot environment.

I've downloaded http://www.supergrubdisk.org/ and installed that to a USB stick and am looking at that, but have never used it before and don't even know if this will work.

Can anyone help me get my bootloader back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find an answer to this and ended up reinstalling :(

Lesson - be careful when prepping live USB sticks to put a destination as if you don't it'll target your local HDD.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to boot your hard disk if you plug in the USB stick that grub was written to.

Once booted do an update-grub.